# Recommendation for Azure Cosmosdb Gremlin Fluent SDK

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

I started working with CosmosDb Graph and using the string based version. I tried a random fluent SDK but didn't work very well. Can someone recommend a fluent SDK?

Comment: Can you please be more specific?

Comment: Sorry, I got confyúsed when using the API. Trying to read some basic data.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on which language you are using you will need to find the correct Gremlin Language Variant which you can find from the Tinkerpop Reference Documentation here: [Tinkerpop Gremlin Language Variants](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/reference/#gremlin-variants)

Comment: Can you provide some details about what didn't work and what you are tryign to accomplish?

Comment: The traversing part was causing issues. Currently went away from it and just using strings with queries